# Java ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> clear() on child clears parent

Tags: java, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> res= new ArrayList();
ArrayList<String> data= new ArrayList();
```

After I add resultset into child and append child into parent I call `.clear()` on then `data` to reset indexes.

The problem is that `.clear()` drops both child and the parent.

Any ideas to why?

In the end from the entire resultset I just get final row duplicated 10 times.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getTemplateTableData() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> res = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList();
    CDb cb = new CDb();
    OracleConnection conn = cb.getConn();
    OraclePreparedStatement ps = null;
    OracleResultSet rs = null;
    OracleResultSetMetaData rsm = null;
    try {
      ps = (OraclePreparedStatement)
              conn.prepareStatement("Select * From Va_User_Infos_V t Where t.User_Id = 1");
      ps.execute();
      rs = (OracleResultSet)ps.getResultSet();
      rsm = (OracleResultSetMetaData)rs.getMetaData();
      while(rs.next()) {
        int col = 2;
        data.clear();
        System.out.println(data);
        while(col < rsm.getColumnCount()) {
          col++;
          data.add(rs.getString(col));
        }
        res.add(data);
        System.out.println(data);
      }
      System.out.println(res);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      cb.done(rs);
      cb.done(ps);
      cb.done(conn);
    }
    return res;
  }
```

Output:

```
[]
[1Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[2Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[3Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[4Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[5Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[6Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[7Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[8Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[9Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[]
[10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]
[[10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8], 
 [10Col-1, Col-2, Col-3, Col-4, Col-5, Col-6, Col-7, Col-8]]
```

Final intention is to parse the parent list and add data into XWPF docx table.

Solution:

```
  while(rs.next()) {
    int col = 2;
    data.clear();
    while(col < rsm.getColumnCount()) {
      col++;
      data.add(rs.getString(col));
    }
    ArrayList clone = (ArrayList)data.clone();
    res.add(clone);
  }
```

Comment: You are adding the same data object over and over again to the res, but not creating new instances of data. So when you add it to res in the first run, and call clear() on the second run you basically also clear res.get(1) elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing: putting a reference to the child list into the parent list.

You are not creating a **copy** of the child list. Just putting references to the **same** list in different places.

Surprise: when you now modify that child list (no matter what you do: adding, removing, clearing, sorting ...) all other references will show you the changed content!

Two solutions:

- create **new** child lists; and do not modify a list **after** adding it to the parent list
- "flatten" your parent list (make it a `List<String>` too); and use `addAll()` to add the **contents** of the child list!

Comment: not sure if i can flatten it, it would mean i would have to add another while loop inside a procedure where I call this function

Comment: i got my data list clone, it worked, thank you. I was stupid to forget about references lol